# Multiple Card Flip jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to have multiple cards flip individually, but I'm not that well versed in jQuery/JS and I'm having issues with figuring out the code, and could use a little help. Also, the tiles aren't flipping back over when clicked.

```js
$('.js-click').on('click', function() {
  $('.card').not(this).removeClass('flipped');
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
$('.js-click1').on('click', function() {
  $('.card').not(this).removeClass('flipped');
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
.flipContainer {
  width: 260px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click1">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue came from trying to find the appropriate `.card` element (looks like it was finding both of them) and then removing a class + toggling a class will always add it:

1. remove .flipped
2. toggle .flipped
3. .flipped is always added

so you'll never turn your cards back over.

Quick fix, look for the clicked element's `parent()` and target that...

```js
$('.js-click').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
.flipContainer {
  width: 260px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! All the solutions given worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

First you'll want to give both cards the class of `js-click` so that you can target both of them with the same `$('.js-click')` selector. Then as you want to flip the target's `.card`, all you have to do is toggle the class `flipped` on **[`$(this).parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)**.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$('.js-click').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
.flipContainer {
  width: 260px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! All the solutions given worked perfectly!

Comment: Follow up, when I add a z-index and position absolute to the .card div and give the button position relative and give it top 200px and right 0 - it goes back to not flipping once its on the blue side.

Answer (score 1):

You are toggling the `flipped` class on all elements with `.card` what you need it to do it just for the associated elements like

```
$(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
```

Moreover, you can reduce your code by assigning `js-click` class to both buttons

Here is snippet

```js
$('.js-click').on('click', function() {
   
  $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
.flipContainer {
  width: 260px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="flipContainer">
  <div class="card">
    <button class="js-click">+</button>
    <div class="front">Custom Installation</div>
    <div class="back">Custom Installation details</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! All the solutions given worked perfectly!